# Trial version Artifactory doesn't starts Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, artifactory

I'm installing trial version on new VM under Ubuntu 20.04.
I've installed it with docker-compose, using this guide: https://jfrog.com/xray/install/
After using config, I get this:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbFFu.png
```

After starting services:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYdXe.png
```

If needed system.yaml:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bEr81.png
After starting Artifactory i can't access it by it's ip, getting error `'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED'` in browser.

UPD. Found one trouble with starting postgreSql. Don't know how to fix it.

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HXVJ.png
```

Comment: Are you using Artifactory or Xray? Based on the screenshots, it seems that you are trying to install Xray.

Comment: If I understand it right, i'm installing whole platform

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in IP-address. Artifactory was starting in docker container with localhost IP for Postgres. Docker has troubles with localhost and 127.0.0.1 IP's, thats why Artifactory and Xray couldnt connect to Postgres. Also I recommend to check login and password in settings of Artifactory for postgres.